# expectation of the number of empty cells

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

You are given a random number, $N$, of balls, where $N$ has a Poisson
distribution with parameter $\lambda > 0$. You then place these balls one by one among
$r$ ($\geq 2$) cells according to the uniform distribution: each ball will be independently
put in cell j with probability $\frac{1}{r}$ , for $j = 1, 2 , .. r$ (Assume that the random
number of balls given to you and the way you place these balls among the cells
are mutually independent.) Introduce the following indicator random variables: for
$j = 1, 2, ... r$  $$I_j= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1  &  \mbox{if cell j is empty}\
             \\ 0, &\mbox{ otherwise,} \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
and denote $X$ to be the number of empty cells i.e $X = \sum_{j=1}^{r}I_j$

**Qn(1)** - Find $E[X]$

**Qn(2)** - Evaluate $P[I_i = 1; I_j = 1 | N = n]$, and then find the probability
$P[I_i=1,I_j=1]$, where $1 \leq i < j \leq r$, and n is a non-negative integer.

**My attempt** -

$E[I_j|N=n] = P[I_j = 1|N=n] = (\frac{r-1}{r})^n $
$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb E[\sum_{i=1}^r I_j \mid N]] = \sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{n=0}^\infty \textbf P[I_j = 1 \mid N = n] \; \textbf P[N = n]$  $= \sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{n=0}^\infty \textbf (\frac{r-1}{r})^n \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n}{n!}$

For Qn1, I'm stuck here. I'm not sure how to simplify this expression.

As for Qn2), I don't really understand what the question is asking me. Shouldn't the probability for $P[I_i = 1; I_j = 1 | N = n]$ be the same as $P[I_i=1,I_j=1]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (1) observe that firstly that $\sum_{i=1}^rc=rc$ and secondly that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=e^a$.

Apply this on $a=\frac{r-1}{r}\lambda$.

---

alternative route and making use of symmetry:

$P\left\{ I_{1}=1\right\} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\left\{ I_{1}=1\mid N=n\right\} P\left\{ N=n\right\} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)^{n}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}=e^{-\frac{\lambda}{r}}$

hence

$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\sum_{i=1}^{r}I_{r}=\sum_{i=1}^{r}\mathbb{E}I_{r}=r\mathbb{E}I_{1}=rP\left\{ I_{1}=1\right\} =re^{-\frac{\lambda}{r}}$

---

On (2)

$P\left\{ I_{1}=1=I_{2}\mid N=n\right\} =\left(1-\frac{2}{r}\right)^{n}$
and $P\left\{ I_{1}=1=I_{2}\right\} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\left\{ I_{1}=1=I_{2}\mid N=n\right\} P\left\{ N=n\right\} $

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: There's a minus missing in the exponent.

Comment: @Dominik Yes, you are right. Thanks, I will repair.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how did u get $P\left\{ I_{1}=1=I_{2}\mid N=n\right\} =\left(1-\frac{2}{r}\right)^{n}$ ?

Comment: If a ball is uniformly placed over $r$ cells then the probability that it is not placed in one of the cells 1 and 2 is $1-\frac2{r}$. If this happens for $n$ balls independently then we end up with probability $(1-\frac2{r})^n$ that the cells 1 and 2 remain empty.

Comment: ah yes it makes sense, thanks for the answer!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\exp(-\lambda)$ is constant and can be pulled to the front of the sum. The remaining inner sum has the value $\exp\left(\frac{r - 1}{r} \lambda\right)$ (remember the representation of $\exp$ as power series).

The outer sum can easily be calculated when you see that the inner sum does not depend on the index of the outer sum.

To answer your second question: Clearly the probabilities are not equal. Note that if you have e.g. $r=2$ the probability is $1$ for $n = 1$ but $\frac{1}{2}$ for $n = 2$.