# Infinite sums with factorials and powers

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble simplifying infinite sums in a problem that has come up in another question: [expectation of the number of empty cells](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752449/expectation-of-the-number-of-empty-cells?newreg=9d42d7406f3944079e4d1915c353bda0). The authors of this thread just skip over the step and I can't figure out how to solve it.

The expressions I can't fathom are:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)^{n}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}=e^{-\frac{\lambda}{r}}$

And the quite similar:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{r}\right)^{n}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!} = ?$

If anyone could give advice on how to simplify these expressions it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Factor $e^{-\lambda}$ out, then set $x = (1 - 1/r) \lambda$ in the first expression and $y = (1 - 2/r) \lambda$ in the second expression. Then use the Taylor series for $e^x$ and $e^y$ respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Recall that for any $\mu > 0$, $e^\mu = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\mu^n}{n!}$.

Now, the first expression can be simplified as follows:
\begin{align}
LHS = & \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(1-\frac 1r\right)^n e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}
\\  = &\  e^{-\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(1-\frac 1r\right)^n \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} && \text{($e^{-\lambda}$ is a constant independent of $n$)}
\\ = &\ e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\lambda-\frac \lambda r\right)^n}{n!} && \text{(Both terms are raised to the same power, so we multiply)}
\\ = & e^{-\lambda} \times e^{\left(\lambda - \frac \lambda r\right)} && \text{$\bigg($ Put $\mu = \lambda - \frac \lambda r$ in the yellow box above$\bigg)$}
\\ = & e^{\frac{-\lambda}{r}} && \text{(multiplying numbers with the same base, add exponents)}
\end{align}

The second expression is very similar, except you will have to put something different for $\mu$ in the yellow box. I leave it to you as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much! The whole problem suddenly feels a lot easier to grasp

Comment: You are welcome! ALso, if you like, you can post the answer to the second question and I will reply to you.